# FileNotFoundException when loading dll

Tags: c#, .net, filenotfoundexception

When I try to execute my program I receive FileNotFoundException, howerver dll exist in the same folder. How is that possible and how to fix the problem? Output below translated from localized messages of Russian Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation:

```
C:\Oleg\bin\fast>FAST.exe

Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Can't load "QuickFASTDotNet.dll"
or dependent component. Can't find this file.
in FAST.FAST..ctor()
in FAST.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Oleg\fast\FAST\FAST\
Program.cs:line 474

C:\Oleg\bin\fast>dir QuickFASTDotNet.dll
    16.02.2012  16:45           117 760 QuickFASTDotNet.dll
```

The same binaries work on my Windows 7 machine (but doesn't work on another Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation machine).

Comment: What is this `C:\Oleg\fast\FAST\FAST\`?

Comment: What is the output path for the compiled executable?  Is the .dll outputted to that directory as well?

Comment: What the assemblies referenced by `QuickFASTDotNet.dll`? are those also there?

Comment: @sll I guess this is cached by debugger, this path is from development machine. I tring to launch "debug" build.

Comment: @sebastian yes they are. binaries works on development machine. When I copy them to another machine they stop working

Comment: @PinnyM dll and executable are in the same directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out [Debugging Assembly Loading Failures](https://web.archive.org/web/20131212004447/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx).

Most likely reason is some related file is not installed in the GAC on you Server machines, or x86/x64 mismatch.

Comment: I have installed Microsoft SDKs to troubleshot the problem because I wanted to retrieve the Fusion log and that's it. Just installing Microsoft SDKs solved the problem, now application starts.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, QuickFASTDotNet.dll call some function of another library and these library not found. You can use [dllexp](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) to check it.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error when the file has been blocked by Windows since it's been copied from another computer. Right click on the dll file and click on "Unblock" button from the security tab

See https://superuser.com/questions/38476/this-file-came-from-another-computer-how-can-i-unblock-all-the-files-in-a