# Why won't my C# app execute on a different machine?

Tags: c#, add-on, filenotfoundexception, quickbooks

I've been developing an app for about 2 months.  It's the first time I've done anything of this size before.  Now that I'm getting close to having all the processes functioning the way I want them to, I'm getting the error below when I try to run the app.

I've created apps before that ran just fine...in fact better on other machines.  But this app is busting my chops.

```
  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:    CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01:    logopicking.exe
  Problem Signature 02:    1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03:    4f4e6509
  Problem Signature 04:    System.Drawing
  Problem Signature 05:    4.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06:    4ba1e086
  Problem Signature 07:    30
  Problem Signature 08:    14
  Problem Signature 09:    System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  OS Version:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1:    0a9e
  Additional Information 2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3:    0a9e
  Additional Information 4:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

So that's the error it gives me.

To add more info I'll post the usings

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Interop.QBFC11;
```

I don't know if there's something wrong with the any of these could be creating an issue that would prevent the app from starting up.

Comment: Just because you have added the references to your project does not mean these files will all automatically be on your target PC or that these files will be registered (if required).

Comment: possible duplicate of [FileNotFoundException when loading dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503429/filenotfoundexception-when-loading-dll)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telling by the System.IO.FileNotFoundException error, you're missing a component or trying to read a file that doesn't exist.

Make sure that you installed the correct version of the .Net framework on this second PC (depends on which version of Visual Studio you're using) and also you'll probably need to install whatever the Quickbooks requires as well on the second machine.

Comment: .Net 4.0 was easy enough to realize, but the Interop file for Quickbooks was easy to overlook.  Both answers helped me.  YAY.

Answer (score 6):

you are getting a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`. Your application is trying to access a file, which it cannot find on the 'different machine'

this link will help you further: http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/258689-NET-20-Win-App-Eror-EventType-clr20r3

taken from there:

"Implement an UnhandledExceptionHandler and log the exception information to the Event Log so that you can get better information about what is causing your application to crash and in what context."

```
// C# 2.0
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(
    delegate(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
      if (e.IsTerminating) {
        object o = e.ExceptionObject;
        Debug.WriteLine(o.ToString());
      }
    }
  );

  // rest of your Main code
}
```

Comment: HAHA...I wrote in the local address of a jpg file that indeed does not exist on the other machine.

Thanks.